# Execute command by creating terminal vscode extension api

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I want to execute command automatically after creating terminal. I have created terminal with the following code but I dont know how can I execute command automatically.

```
const terminal = vscode.window.createTerminal("Open Terminal");
terminal.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `sendText()` method on a `Terminal` instance.  The "text" is for your shell command:

```
sendText(text: string, addNewLine?: boolean): void
```

So

```js
const terminal = vscode.window.createTerminal("Open Terminal");
terminal.show();
terminal.sendText('cd ..', true);   // your command as a string here
```

See [vscode api: Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Terminal).